# Unbind key strokes from process

Tags: c, linux

I have a process that works in a loop good except when any key is accidentally pressed in the keyboard, in which case, the program crashes.

I still need to debug this but it is basically caused by the function poll().

I am not sure yet why this happens, but I would like to unbind all the key strokes happened in the terminal so they are not sent to the process and this crash will not occur.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: start it with `</dev/null`. Oh, and show code. For a problem like this, workarounds are a really bad idea.

Comment: Or you could try closing fd 0 immediately after process start. Depending on the nature of the bug  you observe this might be sufficient.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but is it possible that there is a STDIN_FILENO descriptor in your pollfd set?

Comment: It happened that @pbn was right. This is code I am debugging but I have not develiped myself and indeed, there was a STDIN_FILENO in the pollfd set and this was causing it to fail.

Thank you for the solution.
Best regards!

Comment: I posted it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that there is a STDIN_FILENO descriptor in your pollfd set.

Comment: This was indeed the problem.

Thank you